# CSS: How to break recursiveness when hover

Tags: css, recursion

I have a recursive structure like this:

```
.comment
  .comment-delete
  .comment-replies
     .comment
        .comment-delete
        .comment-replies
           ...
```

where `.comment-delete` is in visibility hidden. I want `.comment-delete` to be visible when hovering the `.comment`, but when hovering the lower-level `.comment`, the top level `.comment-delete` are still visible.

I want to hover the `.comment` and only have its next `.comment-delete` be visible, not any higher-level `.comment-delete`.

The problem is that hovering the 2nd level `.comment` = hovering the 1st level `.comment`.

I cannot put the :hover on anything else but `.comment`.

The question is how to to make it so that hovering .comment in the 2nd level will only leave the 2nd level comment's comment-delete visible, and not also the 1st level comment's delete button?

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/612b7qrg/)

```css
.comment {
  
}
.comment-replies {
  padding-left: 20px
}
.comment-delete {
  display: inline-block;
  width:10px;
  height:10px;
  background: red;
  visibility: hidden;
}

.comment:hover >.comment-delete {
  visibility: visible;
}
```

```html
<div class="comment">
  1st level comment
  <div class="comment-delete"></div>
  <div class="comment-replies">
        <div class="comment">
           2nd level comment
           <div class="comment-delete"></div>
           <div class="comment-replies"></div>
        </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Please don't link to your code. Post it here.

Comment: As you correctly said, "hovering over 2nd level comment means hovering over 1st level comment".  you might need a JS solution to this instead of CSS - are you ok with that?

Comment: @andi I would rather not do that. I was thinking some of these :not :child operators might help. I am testing some stuff right now.

Comment: @ScottMarcus may I ask why not use jsfiddle? I would think that it would be much easier for anyone to just open that link and make some quick test instead of having it on a static page like this.

Comment: Because external links may become broken over time and Stack Overflow is a knowledge base. People will be looking at your question, the comments and the answer for many years to come. If the external link goes bad, your question won't make any sense. Not to mention, making the people that you want to help you jump through an extra hoop, doesn't make it easy for us to help you.

Comment: @Zetoooo you can link your code, but you still should post the relevant parts here, in case the link rots to still keep your question relevant.

Comment: @ScottMarcus Ah ok. Yes that makes a lot of sense. I was just under the impression that jsfiddle is so much more helpful in terms of quick testing. Thanks for the explanation, I will keep that in mind next time!

Comment: @Christoph Ok, I will remember. It makes sense. Thank you! (I will still include the link here: https://jsfiddle.net/612b7qrg/ )

Answer (score 1):

I would forget trying to wrestle CSS or JS to get this working, and just structure your markup differently. Something like this:

```css
.comment {
  
}
.comment-replies {
  padding-left: 20px
}
.comment-delete {
  display: inline-block;
  width:10px;
  height:10px;
  background: red;
  visibility: hidden;
}

.comment-body:hover >.comment-delete {
  visibility: visible;
}
```

```html
<div class="comment">
  <div class="comment-body">
    1st level comment
    <div class="comment-delete"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="comment-replies">
    <div class="comment">
      <div class="comment-body">
        2nd level comment
        <div class="comment-delete"></div>
      </div>
      <div class="comment-replies"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I did think of that, and I might go with this if there is no css magic to be done. It is a problem I have run into multiple times and a quick css fix would be much more helpful than to rewrite a few structures that I have written like this (and many people have too, I am sure). Thank you nonetheless!
I forgot to say that it also breaks some css statements so I wanted to avoid this.